# Parsing data with multiple separators in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of user's favorite movies. In the column "Favorite Movie" are the name of the movie and the producer company. I want to separate the producer company to a new column "Producer Company" but each row has a different separator between the name of the movie and the name of producer company. See an example bellow:

[image: Small Sample of the DataFrame]

Anyone knows any library or any example that I can use to this?
I already tried to use *pandas.Series.str.extract* and *pandas.Series.str.split* but they didn't work well.

Comment: Please post data, not pictures of data.

Comment: There is a probably an easier way, but I'd try to find all the different separators and then use `str.split`

Comment: it's pretty simple with reg expr,  you have [|,by,-] as delimiters.  Can't provide any answers with data pasted as images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.extract` with a regular expression works well

1. delimiters are by,-,| with a space either side
2. actually generates three new columns, 2nd is the delimiter which is dropped
3. joined back to original data frame plus renaming 1st and 3rd columns from `str.extract`
4. no need to keep original column but have for sake of example

```
data = '''User~Favorite Movie 
Allan Michel~The Dark Knight, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Joker | Warner Bros 
Peter Smith~Spider-Man 2 by Columbia Pictures 
George Moore~Spider-Man 2, Spider-Man 3, Venom - Columbia Pictures'''
da = [[i.strip() for i in l.split("~")] for l in data.split("\n")]
df = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
df.join(df["Favorite Movie"].str.extract(r"(.*)[ ](by|-|\|)[ ](.*)").drop([1], axis=1)\
        .rename(columns={0:"Title", 2: "Studio"}))
```

**output**

```
User    Favorite Movie  Title   Studio
0   Allan Michel    The Dark Knight, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer...   The Dark Knight, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer...   Warner Bros
1   Peter Smith Spider-Man 2 by Columbia Pictures   Spider-Man 2    Columbia Pictures
2   George Moore    Spider-Man 2, Spider-Man 3, Venom - Columbia P...   Spider-Man 2, Spider-Man 3, Venom   Columbia Pictures
```